# remapping in rqt_plugins

Tags: ros, remapping, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is that possible? If I launch an rqt node with  tag that does not appear to work... Is it supposed to?

Update with respect to @Dirk Thomas Comment:

Basically, I wanted an image_viewer with a fixed topic (for later adding some fancy overlays and so on...). I took the rqt_image_view (indeed C++!) as start point removed the topic spinner and related functions and subscribed the image_transport from a fixed topic. Works perfectly if the "hard-coded" topic exists. However, I did not manage to remap the topic in a launch file.

So far i tried 2 things (Both work with "hard-coded" topic but not with remap):

1. Remapping in launch file using the phyton script for stand alone launching my_plugin:

   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import sys

   from rqt_gui.main import Main

   main = Main()
   sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='my_plugin'))

Launch file:

```
<launch>

  <node name="my_plugin" pkg="my_plugin" type="my_plugin" >  
    <remap from="/input_topic" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
    
</launch>
```

2. Remapping for rqt_gui and load my_plugin into rqt_gui

Edit 28.08.2014: Anyone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190523/remapping-in-rqt_plugins/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-08-19**:
I should be possible but with the limitation that since all plugins share the same node there can only be a single global remapping. May be it does not work correctly for C++ plugins? What exactly are you trying to do?

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-08-29**:
Okay, thank you! I'll have a look at that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned before It might simply be that this feature is not implemented for the C++ plugins. You could fill a feature request at https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt (or might even consider providing a patch to implement it).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1